# Hybrid search and indexing: words and token metadata in Solr

Tags: solr, metadata, token

I am building a set of plugins for Solr to enable a "hybrid" search which would match either words or **token** (not document!) metadata (specific ID numbers). Same words may have different ID numbers in different context, generated in indexing time by an external application. Such as, "run" may have 12345 in one case and 54321 in another (depends on the context). The ID numbers should have more weight in the search. (They will be provided in the query in search time by the same external application.)

I read about custom fields for documents and I was wondering if we could store a blob there with these IDs, but I am not sure how to include it in the search.

Or should I just pretend these IDs are "synonyms" (maybe surrounding them in some kind of unique marking, like *[:12345:]*) and use the synonym factory tokenizers?

I am new to Solr but I have read the relevant documentation so I think I understand how it all works conceptually. **Performance does not matter at this stage**, this is a PoC. Looks like somewhat similar to: [Search different tokens on different fields in Solr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11314250/search-different-tokens-on-different-fields-in-solr) but not exactly. Oh, and I want to tokenise the text myself, too, but that's not an issue.

EDIT: [removed the bit about payloads, it is irrelevant here. Sorry about the confusion]

Comment: Can you generate all the tokens (across various context) for every word, at the time of indexing? Or does the token change with the runtime context?

Comment: The token changes with the runtime context, but I am going to generate it in index time using the external application, yes.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I've misunderstood, as you've already generated the magic tokens, the only requirement is to see if the magic token value is present in a field, and if it is, score the field higher.

Index the magic token values to one field, and the textual values to another. Use boosting to prioritise matches in the magic token field over a match in the textual values field. The magic token field can probably be an integer field based on `tint` from your description.

When searching, you can generate the search string as:

`q=(token:12345^5 OR text:run) AND (token:32145^5 OR text:fast)`

This should give a match in the token a five times better score than a match in the text field. If you don't care if you match 12345 in the text field as well, you can use:

`q=12345 run 32145 fast&qf=text token^5`

You might have to tweak `mm` to give the required number of hits, depending on what your application needs.

Comment: I was thinking on similar lines, but it seems that `word -> token` relations is `1-n`? Since the token varies with the context?

Comment: Yes, which is why a hit in token should be prioritised higher. If there's just a hit in text, it should still be shown, but ranked lower than if there's a hit in token. If the problem just specified matching tokens, it wouldn't be any more than a match query against the token field.

Comment: Yes, but what's still not clear(to me) is if the tokens are available to be indexed, since the OP mentions they are contextual.

Comment: "Generated in indexing time by an external application", they are available.

Comment: Seems interesting, but if I look for "text:", won't it require abandoning all the other tokenizers? E.g. if the original text was in uppercase and the user is searching in lowercase.

I also wanted to index some other metadata (specifically, syntactic role, e.g. "running" -> "subject") and looking up these as well. 

Can you elaborate on the "magic token field" please? 

@SrikanthVenugopalan: the `word -> token` relation is n-n.

Comment: @VadimBerman I think we need a better example, but different fields use different tokenizer and analyzer chains, so you should be able to solve most cases (just a lowercasefilter is a possibility). If you could expand the question with a proper example, it might be easier to say something more useful. I assumed that you're searching for the token values or the string value, while using payloads tell me you want to boost words depending on their function in the text (subject boosted by x, verb by z). Payloads will work for that.

Comment: Actually, @fiskfisk, your first assumption was right. I just realised, after reading more, that payloads are static, so they clearly don't work for me :( . Is there a way to attach and search attributes to the tokens the way payloads hang and then compare them, or I really need separate fields for that?