# Exception writing large document in Solr

Tags: java, solr

I am trying to insert a large document into Solr but it is giving me the following error:

```
Exception writing document id ba666298-9223-4f80-8069-a5018cc7d1b4 to the index; possible analysis error.. Stacktrace follows:
Message: Exception writing document id ba666298-9223-4f80-8069-a5018cc7d1b4 to the index; possible analysis error.
```

Below is my code to post doc:

```
SolrServer server = new HttpSolrServer("http://localhost:8983/solr/myCore");
Collection<SolrInputDocument> docs = new ArrayList<SolrInputDocument>();
SolrInputDocument doc1 = new SolrInputDocument();
doc1.addField("myString", myString);
docs.add(doc1);

server.add(docs);
server.commit()
```

My document has a size of 34375 characters. I have tried splitting document into smaller size and it is working fine with no issues. Is there a limit on posting document?

Comment: check if this is of any help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26531404/exception-writing-document-id-to-the-index-possible-analysis-error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24947122/indexing-crashes-on-custom-tokenizer

Comment: 34375 bytes are far off any limit in any way, so you probably want to check the complete exception thrown at the Solr side. I'm guessing the actual content is causing the error, and not the length (since changing the content makes it work). It might be caused by invalid UTF-8, failed assumptions in the analysis you're using, etc. More information is needed to say anything definitive.

Comment: How is the filedType of `myString`?

Comment: the fieldType is strings. I am new to solr. I am trying to implement analyzer (solr 5.0.0) , but i can't find schema.xml file in my conf directory instead there is managed_schema and it says do not edit. What should i do to implement my own fieldType?